# how to check with vobject either string is valid vcard or not when dealing with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: python, vcf-vcard, vobject

how to check with vobject either string is valid vcard or not?

Is there some extra method or generall approach with try and catch?

For now I do it as follows:

```
 try:
            vobj = vobject.readOne(vcard_readable)
 except Exception as e:
            error_message = {
                "valid": False,
                "reason": "Invalid vCard\n{0}".format(e)}
```

**How to deal with unicode with VOBJECT?**

Comment: Your current code looks OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code works fine, but generally you don't want to catch `Exception` because this will mask other errors in your code.  For example, if I take your code snippet and put it in a file and then run it...I get no error messages, even though I have not imported the `vobject` module.  This is because that code is actually raising a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    vobj = vobject.readOne(vcard_readable)
NameError: name 'vobject' is not defined
```

but because you're catching *all* exceptions, you're hiding it.  A better technique is to catch only the specific exceptions you expect to receive from the `vobject` module, and let others percolate up normally.

For `vobject`, all of the exceptions it raises are going to be subclasses of `vobject.base.VObjectError`, so the following code would suffice:

```
 try:
            vobj = vobject.readOne(vcard_readable)
 except vobject.base.VObjectError as e:
            error_message = {
                "valid": False,
                "reason": "Invalid vCard\n{0}".format(e)}
```

Comment: I extended the question after it was posted. Full answer is given by me, but anyway I think it is fair to accept your answer as being initialy full. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 vcard = put.get('vcard')
            try:
                vcard_readable = base64.decodestring(vcard)
                quoted_printable_vcard = quopri.encodestring(vcard_readable)
                vobj = vobject.readOne(quoted_printable_vcard)
            except UnicodeEncodeError as e:  # case of bad encoding
                error_message = {
                    "valid": False,
                    "reason": "Invalid vCard\n{0}".format(e)}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_message), status=200)
            except vobject.base.VObjectError as e2:  # case of invalid vcard
                error_message = {
                    "valid": False,
                    "reason": "Invalid vCard format\n{0}".format(e2)}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_message), status=200)
            except:
                error_message = {
                    "valid": False,
                    "reason": "Invalid vCard."}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_message), status=200)
```

OK. I solved it. For **`vobject`** to work with UNICODE (UTF-8) it is required to use:

**`quoted printable encoding.`** - example of what it is below:

```
>>> s = "gżegżółka"
>>> s
'g\xc5\xbceg\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82ka'
>>> import quopri
>>> quopri.encodestring(s)
'g=C5=BCeg=C5=BC=C3=B3=C5=82ka'
```